# [次を検索]でファイルの冒頭に戻るようにしたい

Tags: emeditor

[次を検索] コマンドでは、該当の文字列がそれより下にない場合、
「現在位置より下には～は見つかりませんでした」
と表示されて、その位置で終了します。
これをファイルの先頭に戻って続行させる方法はありますでしょうか。

秀丸では私は次の「一周する」のオプションにチェックを入れていて、これをデフォルトにしています。

http://htom.in.coocan.jp/hmfaq8/2_find.html
「一周する」チェックボックス 下検索の場合、ファイルの一番下まで検索し終わった場合、ファイルの先頭に戻って検索を続行します。上検索の場合は逆になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[検索] ダイアログ ボックスで、[折り返しあり] に✔してください。

Comment: [折り返しあり] に✔でうまく行きました。このオプションを知らず失礼しました。